# Why do I need to import tkinter.messagebox but don't need to import tkinter.Tk() after importing tkinter?

Tags: python, import

There was one error: "AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'messagebox'" even the `import tkinter` already given at the beginning, why no error for the `tkinter.Tk()`statement ?

I have figured that the `import` statement not like the `#include` statement in C language, so I can understand we need to import `tkinter.messagebox` if we want to use it even the `import tkinter` has been given, but what confused me was why the `tkinter.Tk` can work well even though we didn't write something like `import tkinter.Tk`?

```
import time, sys
import tkinter
#import tkinter.messagebox

window = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.messagebox.showwarning()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `tkinter.Tk()` function is part of `tkinter`. However the `messagebox` function is part of `tkinter.messagebox` which is another module in `tkinter`. That's why `tkinter.Tk()` will work just fine with only `tkinter` being imported but `tkinter.messagebox` needs the messagebox module to be imported.

More on the Tkinter modules can be found on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules).

You can get it to work if you either:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

And then call the function like:

```
messagebox.showwarning()
```

---

Or by importing like you commented in your code out:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
```

And calling like you do:

```
tkinter.messagebox.showwarning()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @funie200 ! I understand the difference when learned your explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Because `tkinter.messagebox` is a module, but `tkinter.Tk` is a class.

---

When you do `import some_module`, python looks for a file or directory named `some_module` to import. If `some_module` is a file, that file is executed. If `some_module` is a directory (i.e. a *package*, like `tkinter` is) `some_module/__init__.py` is executed. The module then contains all those variables (classes, functions, etc) that were defined in `__init__.py` and *nothing else*. If there are any sub-modules in this package (like `tkinter.messagebox`), python doesn't automatically import them. That is why `tkinter.messagebox` doesn't exist until you import it.

For illustration purposes, here's what the `tkinter` module's structure *could* look like:

```
tkinter/
    __init__.py
    messagebox.py
    tk.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .tk import Tk
```

`tk.py`:

```
class Tk:
    ...
```

With a setup like this, doing `import tkinter` will automatically import the `Tk` class and make it available as `tkinter.Tk`. But `messagebox.py` won't be imported automatically - you have to do that manually.

(P.S.: If `__init__.py` contained the code `from . import messagebox`, then `import tkinter.messagebox` wouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for your details explanation @Aran-Fey, this might be the perfect answer :)